# Problem with ideal arithmetic in free relations of NFS

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I am studying the number field sieve on Crandall and Pomerance - "Prime numbers: a computational perspective" (2001). Now I am at the free relations chapter and there is something I cannot understand...

Let's take $f$ a monic irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (with degree $d$ and with a root $\alpha$), let $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a prime and let's consider
$$R(p):=\{r\in\mathbb{Z}_p : f(r)\equiv 0 \pmod{p}\}$$
Pomerance asserts that if $R(p)$ is a set of exactly $d$ elements, then the product of the prime ideals $(p,\alpha-r)$ for $r\in R(p)$ in the ring $I$ of algebraic integer of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is equal to $(p)$.

My attempt: $R(p)$ has $d$ elements iff $f=(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_d) \pmod{p}$ with $r_i$ all the distinct elements of $R(p)$, so we have $(\alpha-r_1)\cdots(\alpha-r_d)=kp$ for some integer $k$. Now
$$(p,\alpha-r_1)\cdots(p,\alpha-r_d)=\left(p^d,p^{d-1}(\alpha-r_i),\ldots,(\alpha-r_1)\cdots(\alpha-r_d)\right)=\left(p^d,p^{d-1}(\alpha-r_i),\ldots,kp\right)$$
Now I cannot understand why this ideal should be equal to $(p)$ in $I$...

The inclusion $\left(p^d,p^{d-1}(\alpha-r_i),\ldots,kp\right)\subseteq(p)$ looks quiet easy. In fact, $\alpha\in I$ and $z\in I$ for all $z\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $\alpha-r_i\in I$ and $p\in I$, thus all the generators on the left are in $(p)$.

Comment: Yes, I tried, I simply do not understand how to build $p$ with the element of the product of ideals.

Comment: If $d=1$ it's easy: we have already the generator $p$ in our product of one factor. Let's suppose $d>1$.

Comment: The only remark I can make is the following: Let's take $r_1,r_2\in R(p)$ two different roots in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $r_1 \ne r_2 \pmod{p} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad p\nmid r_1-r_2 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \gcd{(r_1-r_2,p^j)}=1 \quad\forall j\geq1$

Comment: I did check out the book (2nd ed., 2005), and it appears you've given a faithful account of the first paragraph of *Free relations* subsection of **6.2.7 NFS: Further considerations.**  I'm working on a simple example $d=2$ to clarify the computation.

Comment: Apparently your calculation, showing the *product* $(p,\alpha-r_1)\cdots(p,\alpha-r_d)\subseteq (p)$ is the hard part.  Clearly the *intersection* contains $(p)$.  But the ideals $(p,\alpha-r_i)$ were noted to be *coprime* by the authors back in **6.2.2** in the midst of proving Lemma 6.2.1, and thus by Chinese remainder theorem for ideals, the product and intersection are equal!  I'll polish things up and post an Answer.

Comment: For $d=2$ what you would get is 
$$
\begin{align*}
(p,\alpha-r_1)(p,\alpha-r_2) &= (p^2,p(\alpha-r_1),p(\alpha-r_2),(\alpha-r_1)(\alpha-r_2)\\
&=(p)(p,\alpha-r_1,\alpha-r_2,(\alpha-r_1)(\alpha-r_2)/p)
\end{align*}
$$
Since $0\leq r_1,r_2\leq p-1$ and $r_1\neq r_2$, the element $(\alpha-r_1)-(\alpha - r_2) = r_2-r_1$ is in $[1,p-1]$ and coprime to $p$, so you can generate
$$
1 = up + v(r_2-r_1) = up + v((\alpha-r_1)-(\alpha-r_2))
$$
for some $u,v\in\mathbb Z$. The problem with this approach is it becomes messy for large $d$ (you can reduce to $d-1$ case and use induction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be monic irreducible of degree $d$, and let $p\ge d$ be a rational (integer) prime such that $f(x)$ has $d$ distinct roots mod $p$.

For convenience we define the set $R(p) = \{r\in [0,\ldots,p-1] \mid f(r) \equiv 0 \bmod p\}$. By assumptions $|R(p)| = d$.  This slight departure from the notation in the Question has the advantage that each $r_i \in R(p)$ is distinct as both an integer and as a residue mod $p$.  Henceforth we will use the index $1\le i\le d$ to indicate the $r_i \in R(p)$ without explicit mention.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$ in a simple field extension $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, and let $I$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  Certainly $\mathbb Z[\alpha] \subseteq I$, but the containment will sometimes be proper.

The goal is to show that the product of the $d$ ideals $(p,\alpha - r_i)$ in $I$ is equal to the principal ideal $pI$.  A one-line summary of the proof is:

$$ pI \subseteq \bigcap_i (p,\alpha - r_i) \subseteq \prod_i (p,\alpha - r_i) \subseteq pI $$

We will establish each link in this chain of subsets in the sections below.

$\underline{\;pI \subseteq \bigcap_i (p,\alpha - r_i)\;}$

This is the easy part since $p\in (p,\alpha - r_i)$ for each $i$.

$\underline{\;\bigcap_i (p,\alpha - r_i) \subseteq \prod_i (p,\alpha - r_i)\;}$

In fact we have equality of these ideals (since for any finite collection the product of ideals is contained in their intersection) because here the ideal factors are *pairwise coprime*, as the authors Crandall and Pomerance already observed the earlier proof of **Lemma 6.2.1** (p.284 of 2nd ed.).  This coprimality also follows from the Comment above by the OP that $\gcd(p,r_i - r_j) = 1$ whenever $i\neq j$, so $(p,\alpha - r_i) + (p,\alpha - r_j) = I$.

The [equality of the product and intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2442603/product-and-intersection-of-n-ideals) of a finite collection of (pairwise) coprime ideals is often connected with the [Chinese remainder theorem for ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102037/the-chinese-remainder-theorem-for-rings).  For computational aspects of this, see [William Stein's notes](https://www.williamstein.org/papers/ant/html/node31.html).

$\underline{\;\prod_i (p,\alpha - r_i) \subseteq pI\;}$

Consider the typical product of elements, one from each factor, and it should be seen that the inclusion above will follow once we establish:

$$ \prod_i \alpha - r_i \in pI $$

since all the other terms in the implied products contain (at least) one factor $p$.

Let $g(x) = \prod_i x - r_i$, so that $f(x),g(x)$ are both monic polynomials of degree $d$ over the integers.  Considering $f(x)$ instead as a polynomial over finite field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, the distinctness of roots $r_i$ as residues mod $p$ establish (by [polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) and agreement in degree) that:

$$ f(x) \equiv g(x) \bmod p $$

Since $f(\alpha) = 0$ and by the last observation $f(\alpha) - g(\alpha) \in pI$, it follows that $g(\alpha) = f(\alpha) - (f(\alpha) - g(\alpha)) \in pI$ as desired.